# Dynamic query using spring JPARepository

Tags: sql, spring, dynamic, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using jpa2.1 with spring 4.x.x in my project. I have to create a dynamic query on the basis of column name.
for example:

[image]

With the help from `table1` `col1` data `A`,`B`,`C` I have to create a dynamic query on `table2` which will give me all the data of `table2`.

`String s = "select A,B,C from table2 where Enable=Y";`

and pass that value on the repository. But I am not able to create a dynamic query.
How can I create a dynamic query in JPA by using column name so that I get a desired output from `table2`?

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation. This is what you want.

Comment: If you want create a query that's more specific, you can do "custom query" like http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you want your columns to be dynamic you'll have to work either with the `EntityManager` directly or possibly even fall back to a `JdbcTemplate`.

In order to do that you'll create a custom method implementation for your repository and inject the `EntityManager` or `JdbcTemplate` into that.
You use those to select the required data from `table1` and construct and execute the final SQL out of that.